# Is it a fault with php or cache

Tags: php, html

I have a simple test and I cannot for the life of me able to get this to work. In fact I'm going bonkers over it. Its as if there is a problem with images and php. I can show only 1 image, not more. The script appears right. If there is a fix or a cache issue I'm not aware of, please let me know. Thanks. Here is the code in two parts php for calculations server side and html for displaying the two images.

**php**

```
$result = mysqli_query($mydb, "SELECT user FROM `table` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 2");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)){
echo $row[0]; // I use this echo to prove that the user name shows for [0]
echo $row[1]; // I use this echo to prove that the user name shows for [1]

$src1 = 'thumb/'.$row[0].'img1.jpg'; // directory of file
$src2 = 'thumb/'.$row[1].'img1.jpg'; // directory of file 
}
```

**html to show img**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
          <tr>
          <td>
                <img src="<?php echo $src1; ?>" id="srca" alt="srcerra" />
                <img src="<?php echo $src2; ?>" id="srcb" alt="srcerrb" />
          </td>
          </tr>
       </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

The first image shows fine, the second image just gives me the img alt (srcerrb). user (name)'s are different for each file name.

Try it out and see if you get the same result as I do. The image directories are perfect and tested. Cheers.

Comment: You're only selecting 1 column from `table` (the `user` column), so `$row` will only have one element (element 0, and no element 1)..... so if you really are doing `echo $row[1];`, what does it show?

Comment: You're also overwriting your values in your loop

Comment: The table is missing `<tr>` and `<td>` elements.

Comment: You need to put the loop that fetches rows and outputs the `<img>` inside the `<table>`.

Comment: yep a little lazy on the html, so thanx for the heads up. I am hoping to not loop the output but just display it. I see my error re overwrite and was confused about [0] and see that this relates to the column when I thought it related to an array count. Silly me. I will write an update and test it to see if I can get it working with all these wonderful tips.

Comment: Barmar below is definitely a legend. I got it working with his and all of your help here. Don't you love a challenge? Ummm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confusing rows and columns. Your query returns two rows, but each one of them only has one column, which is `$row[0]`. The code should be like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($mydb, "SELECT user FROM `table` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 2");
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result); // get first row
$src1 = 'thumb/'.$row[0].'img1.jpg';
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result); // get second row
$src2 = 'thumb/'.$row[0].'img1.jpg';
```

Comment: ok, I will try this, thanks.... I couldn't understand why it wouldn't populate the image.... cheers

Comment: nope, still doesnt display the image.... it is true the echo of the user is correct (was before with my code) but even with your code it wont show the image. If you try and duplicate what I have done u will see how it wont read a file for the second one.

Comment: I didn't have the filenames in `$src1`. Try the update.

Comment: thanks for update however  I did put them in and it still wont display the second image.

Comment: Are you sure the `user` table has at least 2 rows?

Comment: yep sure does, has 3. When I echo the user (name) it shows the 2 user names but when I extract the image it wont show the second one. your code btw just shows the 1 image twice.

Comment: What do you see when you use `View Source`, is it showing the same URL in both `<img>` elements?

Comment: yep, the image file is the same but the names when I echo them are different.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, you were right.... I copied your code again and this time it works!!!!! My teddy bear is forever grateful!